# I get an error when i try to import libraries

Tags: python, error-handling, compiler-errors, bots, helper

```
import time
import keyboard
import pyautogui
```

When i try to import keyboard and pyautogui i get these errors :

```
Import "keyboard" could not be resolved from source reportMissingModuleSource
Import "pyautogui" could not be resolved from source reportMissingModuleSource
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed `keyboard` and `pyautogui` ?  eg: `pip install keyboard`.
Also if you are using a virtual environment, map to the correct python interpreter. Activate it and install the dependencies then try to import the modules again

Comment: How can i do that ? (Also sorry , i am sooo new at python)

Comment: @35FAN35 i have updated the answer. Could you please try that

Comment: Okay i will try